# array sum recursion function doesn't work

Tags: c, recursion

hello everyone I'm puzzled why this function returns 0 every time. I use arr[0] as index and define it size of array in main func.

```
int sum_array (int arr[]) {
    int result;
    arr[0] = arr[0]-1;
    if(arr[0]<=0){
        return 0;
    }
    result = ((sum_array(arr))+(arr[arr[0]]));
    return result;


}
```

If I use `if(arr[0]<=1)` instead of `if(arr[0]<=0)` it returns 5. I also don't get why it returns 5.

```
array = {0,1,1,2,3,3,4}
```

Comment: The line `result=((sum_array(arr))+(arr[arr[0]]));` exhibits undefined behaviour because the result is dependant on the evaulation order of `+` as the left side modifies `arr[0]` and the right side reads the same value. Your program is ill-formed. Therefore the compiler is under no obligation to output anything sensible.

Comment: Thanks bro. it helped a lot <3

Comment: ... also, the line mentioned above is practically unreachable with your array input because the `if` statement will be true in the first call and any subsequent call as well.

Comment: of course, if you don't post the code in main.... or you don' t say what do you pass as the arrary parameter, it's impossible to guess what is even the purpose of your routine.  Please, have a look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. uses recursion
2. performs the desired functionality

and now, the proposed code:

```
int sum_array (int arr[]) 
{
    if(arr[0]<=0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int index = arr[0];
        arr[0]--;
        return arr[ index ] + sum_array( arr );
    }
}
```